# JS Game set responsive height and width to canvas using CSS instead of JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script for a sample game coded by someone else to work using the phaser.js. I am mostly a HTML/CSS guy and my JS knowledge is very basic. Right now the game specifies the height and width "832" and "508" on the canvas using JS. I want the game to be responsive i.e. the height and width be set using CSS.

This is how I call the game:

```
    <div class="game-box">
         <div class="game-container">
              <div id="phaser-div">

              </div>
         </div><!-- end game-container -->
    </div><!-- end game-box -->
```

And this is the script for the game:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(832, 508, Phaser.WEBGL, 'phaser-div', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

var background;
var filter;

function preload() {

    var urlBase = location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    game.load.image('phaser', urlBase + 'games/game001/game001-logo.png');
    game.load.script('filter', urlBase + 'games/game001/marble.js');

    this.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL; this.game.scale.setShowAll(); window.addEventListener('resize', function () { this.game.scale.refresh(); }); this.game.scale.refresh();
}

function create() {

    var logo = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'phaser');
    logo.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);

    background = game.add.sprite(0, 0);
    background.width = 832;
    background.height = 508;

    filter = game.add.filter('Marble', 832, 508);
    filter.alpha = 0.2;

    //  The following properties are available (shown at default values)

    //  filter.speed = 10.0;
    //  filter.intensity = 0.30;

    background.filters = [filter];

}

function update() {

    filter.update();

}
```

I tried setting width and height using "#phaser-div canvas" selector in the CSS, but it didn't work. Let me know how this can be possible.

Many Thanks.

Comment: it has to do with the fact that canvas has has a width and height property. use the sytle.width instead

Comment: So should I change background.width = 832; to background.style.width = 832 and background.height = 508; to background.style.height=508? Any other places that I should modify?

Comment: That is right. canvas has properties that control the point matrix. These are unfortunately called width and height which is where your confusion is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `$(HTMLElement).height()`and `$(HTMLElement).width()`to receive the height and width of the element, so you could respond accordingly. This allows you to avoid using static values (pixels) and use a flexible layout instead (defining dimensions in % or vw).

Comment: Can you please make the changes to the JS code I have written in the question as I am an HTML/CSS guy and my JavaScript knowledge is very basic. Thanks a bunch!